# Why doesn't Go subroutine get executed

Tags: go

I'm learning go, following the online tutorial "A tour of Go".

In this excercise: https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/10

Before going on to solve the problem, I wanted to try something simple:

```
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    fmt.Println("Hello from Crawl")
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    for _, u := range urls {
        fmt.Println("in loop with u = %s", u)
        go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher) //I added "go" here
    }
}
```

The only thing I added is the `go` command right before the recursive call to `Crawl`. I expected it should not change much to the behavior.

However the printout is:

```
Hello from Crawl
found: http://golang.org/ "The Go Programming Language"
in loop with u =  http://golang.org/pkg/
in loop with u =  http://golang.org/cmd/
```

I expected to see `Hello from Crawl` for each iteration of the loop. 
Why doesn't my `Crawl` subroutine get executed?

Comment: I agree that the linked question answers mine as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your goroutines started, but ended before doing what you want to do because your `main()` finished. Execution of goroutines is independent of the main program like threads, but will be terminated when program stops. So you need a [`WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) to wait for the goroutines to finish their jobs or simply call `time.Sleep()` to make the main program sleep for a while.

Comment: The tutorial did not cover `WaitGroup` yet, but thank you to both of you, at least I understand the issue now.

Comment: you can use channel instead of `WaitGroup`, the essence here, is the fact you need to wait for go routine to complete

Comment: @NathanH You're welcome and keep going:)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to make sure that all your go routines ends before your program finishes, I'd refactor your code to something similar to this:

```
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    fmt.Println("Hello from Crawl")
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
   // Adding waiting group to make sure go routines finishes
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(len(urls))
    for _, u := range urls {
        fmt.Println("in loop with u = %s", u)
        go func() {
           defer wg.Done()
           Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher)
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```